# Get random position on surface

Tags: vector-spaces, normal-distribution, surfaces

I'd like to get a random position on a surface of an object, and also follow it's normals.

Example, let's say I have a sphere, I can get all the face, normal and vertex positions and well as their normals, however, I want to randomly get a vector (x,y,z) to positon the object on the surface randomly, as well as orient this object to the facing normals of the closest component.

I'm using Maya for this, it's not necessarily  going to ever be a spherical surface either, however I can gather an array of vertex/edge/face information to use.

Comment: Sounds like you don't really have a sphere. You have a bunch of polygons that approximate a sphere. That chnages the problem, somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{S}{\rm P}\left(\vec{r}\right)\,{\rm d}S
=
{\rm P}\left(\vec{r}\right)\int_{S}{\rm d}S
=
{\rm P}\left(\vec{r}\right)\,4\pi a^{2} = 1
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
{\rm P}\left(\vec{r}\right)= {1 \over 4\pi a^{2}}
$$

$$
1
=
\int_{S}{1 \over 4\pi a^{2}}\,{\rm d}S
=
\int_{0}^{\pi}{1 \over 2}\,\sin\left(\theta\right)\,{\rm d}\theta
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{1 \over 2\pi}\,{\rm d}\phi
$$

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
{1 \over 2}\,\sin\left(\theta\right)\,{\rm d}\theta
& = &
{\rm d}\xi_{\theta}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\theta
=
2\arcsin\left(\xi_{\theta}^{1/2}\right)
\\
{1 \over 2\pi}\,{\rm d}\phi
& = &
{\rm d}\xi_{\phi}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\phi
=
2\pi\xi_{\phi}
\end{array}
$$

With
$
\sin\left(\theta\right)
=
2\sin\left(\theta \over 2\right)\cos\left(\theta \over 2\right)
=
2\sqrt{\xi_{\theta}\left(1 - \xi_{\theta}\right)}
$
and
$
\cos\left(\theta\right)
=
1 - 2\sin^{2}\left(\theta \over 2\right)
=
1 - 2\xi_{\theta}
$

Generate random numbers $\xi_{\theta}$ and $\xi_{\phi}$ in $\left\lbrack 0, 1\right)$.
You get a random vector $x\,\hat{x} + y\,\hat{y} + z\,\hat{z}$ in the surface of a sphere of radius $a$:

$$
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{rcl}
x
& = &
a\sin\left(\theta\right)\cos\left(\phi\right)
=
2a\,\sqrt{\,\xi_{\theta}\left(1 - \xi_{\theta}\right)\,}\,\cos\left(2\pi\xi_{\phi}\right)
\\[2mm]
y
& = &
a\sin\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(\phi\right)
=
2a\,\sqrt{\,\xi_{\theta}\left(1 - \xi_{\theta}\right)\,}\,\sin\left(2\pi\xi_{\phi}\right)
\\[2mm]
z
& = &
a\cos\left(\theta\right)
=
a\left(1 - 2\xi_{\theta}\right)
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: Wow, this looks incredibly complex! However will this work on any shape as my description states? Not just a sphere?

Comment: Just for the sphere. It's the idea.

Comment: It's very cool, however I did state that I needed it for any surface :(

Comment: @ShannonHochkins  For any surface, it's better to know it to look for symmetries, etc…